# "Amix" and "adelay" combined leads to "Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, delay, mixing

I was trying to add to audio clips together (using `amix`) while delaying one of them (with `adelay`). I used the following command

```bash
ffmpeg -i org/onclassical_demo_luisi_chopin_scherzo_2_31_small-version_ii-ending.wav \
-i org/all_u_had_2_say.wav -filter_complex \
"[1]adelay=1000[del1];[0][del1]amix" out.wav
```

and get the following output

```
ffmpeg version N-77387-g9d38f06 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavcodec     57. 18.100 / 57. 18.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 21.100 /  6. 21.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'org/onclassical_demo_luisi_chopin_scherzo_2_31_small-version_ii-ending.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:18.26, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from 'org/all_u_had_2_say.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:03.85, bitrate: 88 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 88 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'out.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf57.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.18.100 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_u8) -> adelay
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory
size=      83kB time=00:00:03.85 bitrate= 176.6kbits/s speed= 213x    
video:0kB audio:83kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.091808%
```

Maybe there is some incompatibility between the streams (`pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels` vs. `pcm_u8, 11025 Hz, 1 channel`) that need to be handled first, but running only `amix` works so that doesn't actually seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try new build. Or the command below with the current one:

```
ffmpeg -i org/onclassical_demo_luisi_chopin_scherzo_2_31_small-version_ii-ending.wav \
-i org/all_u_had_2_say.wav -filter_complex \
"[0]aresample=48000,aformat=fltp[a];  
[1]aresample=48000,aformat=fltp,asetpts=PTS+(1.000/TB)[del1]; \
[a][del1]amix" out.wav
```

Comment: Gives me the exact same error: "Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: Strange. I tried with similar set of inputs both adelay and asetpts and both work. Try with latest snapshot build.

Comment: Using a newer build fixed the problem and my original command now runs. Put that in your answer and I'll accept it. The revised command works on both builds, so that's great to know also!

Comment: These versions both work with `adelay`: `N-52845-g674cc26-static` and `N-78373-ga73b23e` that I compiled myself.